# How to get all deleted local files from remote using GIT

Tags: linux, git

I have a local directory with multiple files. These files
are already stored in remote git (BitBucket).

I accidentally deleted these files locally, how can I 
get it back from the remote repository?

Answer (score 2):

Did you commit the deletions?

If not, you can use `git checkout -- file` to recover the files.

If you did, you can `git reset` to a previous commit where the files still existed.

If you need a more fine-tuned approach, you can `git clone` your remote repository to a new directory and then use file operations to copy files from the copy to your original repository.

Comment: I didn't commit the  deletions.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to get them from remote if you already had those files locally.

You can use:

```
git checkout -- <deleted file name>
```

You can also use file and directory wildcards:

```
git checkout -- dir1/*
```

---

> ```
> git checkout [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>...
> ```
>
> Overwrite paths in the working tree by replacing with the contents in the index or in the `<tree-ish>` (most often a commit). When a `<tree-ish>` is given, the paths that match the `<pathspec>` are updated both in the index and in the working tree.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset your local master branch to the remote repo master like so:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just deleted the file and do not run `git add`, then

```
git checkout -- <file>
```

If you have run `git add`, then

```
git reset HEAD <file>
git checkout -- <file>
```

If you have commit it to local repository, then

```
git reset --hard <the_commit_before_bad_commit>
```

Anyway, you'd better backup all the files when you try it.